# Can't get to virtual host working on CentOS

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, virtualhost

I'm been banging my head trying to get the virtual host working on AWS EC2 Linux AMI; looks like a flavor of CentOS

I did the following:
1) set up my .conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mysub.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/mysub.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I put in error log, etc. but removed all that to see if removing helps

2) restart server

3) point mysub.domain.com A record to my aws ip

I can get to mysub.domain.com but the default "Your AWS Elastic Beanstalk PHP application" page comes up

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

Check security group of ec2 instance . Make sure required port inbound traffic is allowed .

Launch your ec2 instance in public subnet .

Reference url

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/wt2-apache-web-server.html

Comment: The security group and subnet are fine because the OP is able to access the default "Your AWS Elastic Beanstalk PHP application" page which means traffic is reaching the instance.

Comment: oops is missed that its showing elastic beanstalk page . can you please confirm that its elastic beanstalk or EC2 instance?